# How to replace multiple values in a raster as NA and save output files in an output directory?

Tags: r, replace, raster, na, missing-data

I have multiple .tiff images such as

```
20000101
20000113
20000124
.
.
.
20201224
(format is yyyymmdd)
```

The raster files may contain 65533, 65534 and 65535 values as missing data. I want to replace these values with NA because later, I need to calculate mean of these files and missing data may cause a problem.

I am using the following code to achieve the same. Is the code correct? I am doing it in R

```
r1 <- list.files(path="D:/Test/", pattern=".tiff",full.names = TRUE)
s1 <- stack(r1)
x1 <- clamp(s1, useValues=FALSE)
y1 <- reclassify(s1, cbind(-Inf, 65535, NA), right=FALSE)
```

How can I convert 65533 and 65534 values also to NA in the same code.

How can I export the output rasters files to a new output directory such as D:/Test/Out with same filenames as input raster files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that all the real values are (much) lower. In that case, you could do

```
library(terra)
ff <- list.files(path="D:/Test/", pattern=".tiff$", full.names=TRUE)
r <- rast(ff)
x <- clamp(r, -Inf, 65500, values=FALSE)
```

Otherwise, you might do

```
x <- classify(r, cbind(65533:65535, NA))
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert. 65533-65535 are the real values denoting NA in my data. How can I save the output in a new directory? I am unable to do it using writeRaster.